# Limit RDP to one application?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

Currently I have a windows 8.1 machine that a couple users can RDP into, to use quickbooks and our timecard software via the web/WAN.

I plan on updating my old windows 8.1 RDP serer with another PC running server 2016 and CAL licenses for multiple RDP sessions.

Is there an easy way to setup an RDP session to just login and have access to one or two applications without manually denying user access to every single thing on the PC?

Or maybe something like RemoteApp is the way to go? I've just never dealt with a domain before and not sure the effects/ headaches of deploying a domain server in our network just to run a couple RDP like sessions. Only ever worked in a workgroup environment.

Basically looking for the easiest/best way to give remote access to a couple applications. in my case it's quickbooks and wasptime

Comment: Remote Desktop Services can do this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/welcome-to-rds

Comment: I believe to take advantage of fancy RDS features you have to setup the Server as a Domain correct? Just want to make sure there is no realistic way to do this via a workgroup/RDP method before I jump into setting up and learning a Domain/RDS/RemoteApp method of some sort.